# Are the addresses of array elements guaranteed to increase

Tags: c

When I define and initialize an Array `a`:

Is it absolutely absolutely safe, that if `(&(a[x]) > &(a[y]))` holds, `x > y` is implied?

I am worried about some weird exceptional memory address stuff I have no idea about.

Comment: Thanks :) (forgot to add, that I allocate memory for a on heap, but I don't think that affects your answer, does it?)

Comment: What did you find? What makes you think it is not or at least the comparison behaves as-if?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed.  Section 6.5.8p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Relational Operators states:

> **When  two  pointers  are  compared,  the  result  depends  on  the 
>   relative  locations  in  the address space of the objects pointed to.** 
>   If two pointers to object types both point to the same  object,  or 
>   both  point  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  same  array 
>   object,  they compare  equal.   If  the  objects  pointed  to  are 
>   members  of  the  same  aggregate  object, pointers  to  structure 
>   members  declared  later  compare  greater  than  pointers  to 
>   members declared  earlier  in  the  structure,  and  **pointers  to 
>   array  elements  with  larger  subscript values compare greater than
>   pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values.**
>   All  pointers  to  members  of  the  same  union  object  compare 
>   equal.   If  the expression P points  to  an  element  of  an  array 
>   object  and  the  expression Q points  to  the last element of the
>   same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P
>   . In all other cases, the behavior is undefined

So even if you have strange memory layouts, the language guarantees that the address of an array element with a higher subscript will compare greater that the address of an array element with a lower subscript.  As long as the array subscripts are valid the comparison will hold.

Comment: Particularly relevant for architectures such as x86 where the stack is expected to grow downwards.

Comment: @GovindParmar The bytes of an object on x86 still increase even on the stack.  It's just that new stack objects are created at lower addresses.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If `x>y` then `&a[x] > &a[y]`, if both elements of the array exist, or `a[x]` is one element past the end of the array. Otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Note: I see your question asks the inverse of my above answer. The inverse is also true: if the address is greater, then its index is greater, *if the address is a whole number of elements apart*. Normally the compiler handles this and `&a[x]+1` is `&a[x+1]`. The compiler translates the `+1` in the first expression to adding the number of bytes of the element size.

Answer (score 1):

Since, (1) `a[x]` is `*(a+x)`, and consequently (2) `&(a[x]) = a+x`

```
    x < y 
=>  a+x < a+y
=> &(*(a+x)) < &(*(a+y))  // from (2)  
=> &(a[x]) < &(a[y])      // from (1)
```